# Download Firebase Storage Synchronously

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, synchronization, firebase-storage

I am working on downloading an image from Firebase Storage and displaying it on a table view. I have been using this:

```
referenceOfImage.data(withMaxSize: 100 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
    if let error = error {
        print(error)
    } else {
        guard let data = data else {
            print("no data")
            return
        }
        guard let image = UIImage(data: data) else {
            print("no image")
            return
        }
        //use image

    }
}
```

However, according to documentation, the task

> Asynchronously downloads the object at the FIRStorageReference to an NSData object in memory.

I am currently using a loop to download multiple images and it would work better if I could synchronously download the images (otherwise loop would continue and the task would be incomplete). How can I download the image synchronously? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not. These methods are asynchronous because they require server calls, and making them synchronous would block the main thread and cause very poor UX and performance. You could set up your completion call to do a bit of recursion, perhaps?

Stick the image load into a function that takes an array of things to fetch, the current index, and a selector to call when finished. Have a terminating condition (index == array.count), which calls the selector you want to happen when all images are loaded, otherwise fetch the image at the index, and in the completion handler, increment the index and fetch the next image by calling the same method.

Comment: I use retrofit and each server call is made from IO thread, so this can be done synchronous without problems for UI thread. The point is to use straight programming style without callbacks

Comment: Yes, I am looking for synchronous calls for the same reason. Kotlin Coroutines.

Comment: is recursively calling a function that downloads a file from firebase storage a good approach?